# .net mvc razor dropdowns for foreign keys

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, viewmodel

Ok, this seemed simple, but is making my head spin.

I have created models based on CodeFirst.

```
public class Category
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SubCategory
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Category category { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now when i auto-generate the controller and view for SubCategory it (out-of-the-box) lets me create new SubCategory objects without specifying the Category (even through it correctly creates a foreign key relation to the Category table in the DB).

So i though ok, i'll just drop a drop down in the create.cshtml file and have it use that.

after some while i succeed by adding this to the controller:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(db.Category.ToList(),"ID","Name");
        return View();
    }
```

and this to the view:

```
    @Html.DropDownList(model => model.category, "Categories")
```

But now the object does not automatically catch that i want to use this for my foreign key, so when i stop the code at the POST method it still displays the object with NULL in the category field.

I guess my question is twofold. How should i do this? and if my method is right so far, what am i missing?

I just want the new object which is saved to the SubCategory table to include the foreign key to Category.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to define a scalar property named `CategoryId` in your `SubCategory` class

```
public class SubCategory
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public Category category { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then correctly map it in EF

After that you put

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.CategoryID, category SelectList instance)
)
```

Other option is to create a custom model binder to bind `Category` type.

Comment: Im sorry, i was trying to follow this, but i having problem with this: @Html.DropDownList(model => model.CategoryID, "Categories"), error: CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type'....

Comment: @Asinox You have to pass an instance of [SelectList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.aspx) containing `Categories` as the second argument