# ASP MVC 3 how to make DisplayFor show the Value of the a FK?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

im new new with ASP MVC, im having a problem showing the value of a FK in the Details View.

The Displayfor just show the ID of the Field and i want to show the value:

i have 2 models like this:

```
namespace APP.Models
{

    public class Category{

        public int ID{get;set;}
        public string Name {get;set;}
    }

    public class Book{

        public int ID{get;set;}
        public string Title{get;set;}
        public int CategoryID{get;set;}
    }

}
```

So how in my Details view i can show for Category Name?:

```
@Html.Displayfor(model = > model.??)
```

I want to display the Category Name and not the Category ID

Thanks you guys

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your model to look like below

```
public class Book{

    public int ID{get;set;}
    public string Title{get;set;}
    public int CategoryID{get;set;}
    public Category Category{get;set;}
}
```

then

```
@Html.Displayfor(model => model.Category.Name)
```

Edit: displaying categories

Pass the category list to the view from controller action

```
ViewBag.Categories = //get all categories
```

Then in your view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    book => book.CategoryID,
    new SelectList((IEnumerable<Category>)ViewBag.Categories, "ID", "Name")
)
```

Comment: Thanks Erang, i know that was perfect, but now my DropDownList is give me a error about.... how i will make a DropDownList with all Categories?

Comment: @Asinox edited answer. there are plenty of tutorial that teach you the basics of mvc

Comment: Sorry Eranga, i know, but in tired to try example, and know in your example, i have a error about (IEnumerable<Category>) some wrong with "Category".. but it's ok, im browsing :)
Thanks you

Comment: :) check this question and answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366892/net-mvc-razor-dropdowns-for-foreign-keys/